# How to add a new property to model-class without extending it in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, properties, viewmodel

My View contains a ListView (ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection) and I want to show the Items as CheckBoxes with some text (bound to the Name-property of my model-class). This is no problem so far, but I have a hard time to decide where to place the ***"IsChecked"***-property, that I need to bind to (to know which items have been checked).
 I could just add it to my model-class, but this feels not correct and I don't want to "pollute" my model. My other idea is to extend the model-class which results in a new file, but this feels also not right. Any suggestions?
***view***

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <CheckBox Foreground="Black"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

***viewModel***

```
private ObservableCollection<Customer> customerCollection = LoadCustomerCollection();
public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerCollection { get => customerCollection; set => customerCollection = value; }
```

***model-class***:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set 
            {
                if(value != this.id)
                {
                    id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set 
            {
                if(value != this.name)
                {
                    name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your Customer class is not realy a model, it is more of a viewmodel(implementing INotifyPropertyChanged is not required in a model).

Comment: Yeah you are correct.I have seen many discussions if you should/can implement it in the model or not. The only solution I know is to use "proxy-properties" in the ViewModel if you want to implement it there..But any ideas for the actual topic?

Comment: If you want to have `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>` in the ItemTemplate, you would obviously have to add an IsChecked property to the item class, i.e. to Customer. Do not overcomplicate it.

Comment: Yeah this will absolutely work, but basically "IsChecked" does not belong there, you know what I mean? It's a bit overthought maybe, but I am searching the "clean" way to make it better in the future ;)

Comment: It does absolutely belong there. Otherwise, bind the ItemsSource to a CustomerViewModel collection, where CustomerViewModel somehow wraps a Custumer, e.g. by inheritance or composition.

Comment: Thank you so far! Ok if I add this to the model, does this mean that everytime I need some other binding that has influence to my view, I should add it to the model? The second solution you provide seems clean, but also a bit overhead (regarding the bloat of files in the future)..hard for me to decide

Comment: The item class obviously needs to expose all the properties that you want to bind to. Whether you put them all into Customer or all into CustomerViewModel is up to you. This does of course not mean more classes for more properties. As a general note, more classes doesn't necessarily mean more files. There may be multiple class in a single C# file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213872/discussion-between-wulf11-and-clemens).

Answer (score -1):

My take on MVVM is :-

**Model** classes hold data and nothing else - one model instance corresponds to one record in a data table.

**Wrapper ViewModel** classes exist in parallel with model classes to hold non-data properties (such as IsSelected in your case), and also links between Model instances such as parent-child relationships. A wrapper viewmodel exposes a model class instance as a property, so you can bind directly to the model's properties rather than having to create facade properties on the wrapper.

**Standard ViewModel** classes are the grand controllers and data providers for the View.

See my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-viewmodel-1/) for a more detailed discussion on this point.

Comment: Will read through you blog post! Thanks for that so far! Can you tell me how you structure your directories respectively where you put you Wrapper ViewModel files?

Comment: I tend to make separate projects for Models and WVMs distinct from the main application as they are often used by multiple layers within the project - eg database, web services etc.